# DefaultClient scope migrating from App Engine (Go) 1.9 to 1.11

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-play-developer-api

I've recently been migrating an App Engine (Go) app from Go 1.9 to 1.11.  I've followed the steps in the
[Migrating your App Engine app from Go 1.9 to Go 1.11](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go111/go-differences) document, excluding the optional ones.  I plan on doing the optional tasks later once I get this working.

I get the app to build and I can deploy it just fine.  Most of everything works fine, with the exception of one API that is used to look up some info on a Google Play IAP.  When I do that, I get the following error:

> Error 403: Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes., insufficientPermissions

I've checked, and the scope that I'm using is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher`, which is still the scope listed in the [Google Play Developer API documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get).

I'm using the App Engine default service account for the client by calling `DefaultClient` from the `golang.org/x/oauth2/google` library, which returns a client without an error

When I test the same code with Go 1.9, there are no authentication issues at all, and the API works.  I'm guessing that these is something in the authentication setup which has changed but I can't find any documentation on it, nor on what I should do differently.

I have to imagine that a lot of people have had to do this migration, and I can't find any posts with this problem, so I'm lost as to why I'm getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in the differences of runtime in Go 1.9 and 1.11. It doesn't seem to allow you to use Application Default Credentials anymore, you have to set them via a JSON file in 1.11. I found someone who had a very similar issue to you and they used a workaround by uploading a key and using that to get a Client.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53733206/11928097)

Let me know.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks.  One would think that such a major change would be covered in the documentation though.

Comment: I've tried setting up a service account and using that, but now the error that I get is "Error 401: The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation., permissionDenied".  I've even given the service account project wide "owner" permission instead of the usual "editor", and I still get the same error.

Comment: I've been looking into it John, and oddly enough it seems that many people that had a similar issue are commenting that it somehow takes 24-48h for the permissions to propagate. Have a look [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1382#issuecomment-471179616), we will investigate further if that isn't the case. Let me know

Comment: Stefan, is there a reason that the Application Default Credentials are no longer supported.  This seems like a major change, but I've found no documentation on this anywhere, so it's not even clear if it's intentional or a bug.

Comment: There isn't a reason or an official documentation stating that Application Default Credentials are no longer supported,  what i gave you as an answer was a workaround for people that had an issue similar to yours. Let's try and single it out, if it is a bug (which i incline to think it's not) we will report it. I have another idea that we can try. If you go to IAM -> Service Accounts -> App Engine Default Service Account -> Create Key. As you had permissions for your default service accounts, attempt to do the workaround with that key, that way we can single out if it's the 24-48h thing.

Comment: Stefan, I set up a new service account and used the JSON file from that to authenticate.  That initially didn't work, but after waiting for 24-48 hours, it has started working without me changing anything on my side.  It seems to me that there are two bugs here on Google's side.  1) The default service accounts aren't authenticating properly with Go 1.11 (I've confirmed that they still work on Go 1.9).  2) After setting the permissions, there is a really long time for those permissions to propagate through the system.  I'm marking this issue as solved in the mean time.